# How to check various values of same parameter

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a custom command which looks as below:

```
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 1
```

However, the value of `i` can be anything from `1 to 4`
I want to modify the custom command so that it accounts for all the values of `i from 1 to 4` in a single command

As of now, I have written it like as below:

```
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 1
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 2
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 3
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 4
```

I want to write a single command which accounts for all the `4 values`

Comment: With bash only: `for i in {1..4}; do echo bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i "$i"; done`

Comment: What do you mean by single command? Technically, `{ bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 1; bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 2; bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 3; bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 4; }` is a single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo {1..4} | xargs -n 1 echo bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i
```

Output:

```
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 1
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 2
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 3
bashcustomCommand cfgAlert -i 4
```

Remove second `echo` if everything looks fine.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good catch. I've updated my answer to rule out any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are assigning the value to `$i` for this example.

```
if [[ a == "$i" ]]
then for this in {1..4}
     do  "$0" "$1" -i "$this"
     done
     exit
fi
```

If it's 1, 2, 3, or 4, it will do what it always does.
If it's `a`, it will cycle through those in subcalls and then exit.

I'd add error checking and such, but this will keep you from having to type the loop on the command line.